# How can higher dimension spaces have smaller unit balls?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

I have recently been shown the gamma function and a few of its uses, and one of those is calculating the measure of the unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The formula shows the measure going to zero (rather fast, actually) as n grows greater.

I have understood the proof, but it was achieved through some artifacts of integration, and it does not provide a geometric understanding of what is happening.

The result was justified by mentioning that the (hyper)cube that surrounds the sphere has a diagonal of $2^{n/2}$ and that since the measure is, intuitively, how many tiny cubes can I fit inside the sphere, if the volume of the cube is fixed and grows bigger relative to the sphere, then it is the sphere that is becoming smaller overall.

I cannot however visualize this: in fact, the cube has a side length of 2, which translates to a volume of 2^n, which is also growing...

Moreover, an $\infty$-dimensional space has a unit ball of measure $\infty$ (I proved this for $C(0, 1)$), which seems to contrast with the "limit" of the size of $D^n$, the ball of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Can anyone give an intuitive ("geometric") reason for why the unit balls grow smaller as n increases?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: @Travis edited the question

Comment: See my answer on a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778053/limit-of-n-1-measure-of-the-boundary-of-a-sphere/1778183#1778183

Comment: What do you mean when you say a ball in an infinite-dimensional space has infinite measure?  How are you defining the measure?

Comment: @EricWofsey maybe I remember that part incorrectly. I actually showed that I could fit infinitely many disjoint balls of positive radius inside the unit ball.

Comment: @lastresort I read it, but I still can't see how fitting the ball inside a growing cube forces it to go to zero. Yes, the ratio becomes smaller, but that could simply mean that the ball grows at a smaller rate than the cube it sits in (which is what happens for n up to 7).

Comment: @EricWofsey yup, that'll teach me to search better. Thanks